# Unable to select/copy paste from SweetAlert box

Tags: javascript, copy-paste, sweetalert

I have an issue that I'm not sure how to solve.  I'm using SweetAlert to display a message to a user.  I'd like to be able to select copy some of the next but this doesn't seem to be working.

My sweet alert code is:

```
    swal({
            title: "Alert Box Title",
            text: "Select any of this text",
            type: "warning",
            allowEscapeKey: false,
            allowOutsideClick: false,
            showCancelButton: true,
            showConfirmButton: true,
            cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
            confirmButtonText: "Confirm",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            animation: true,
            html: true
    },
```

No issues with the alert itself - works exactly as I would expect.  Just no ability to select/copy text.  I'm far from a Javascript expert so I just can't figure out of this is a setting I'm missing or some other bit of code I need to implement.  Thank you!

UPDATE:
Using Chrome Developer tools, I've identified the issue.  When the code is generated, I get:

```
<div class="sweet-alert showSweetAlert visible" tabindex="-1" .... >
```

It seems to be the tabindex causing it. If I remove that using developer tools, I'm able to select/copy no issue.  I guess I need to dig in and figure out how to change the tabindex but just not sure if that will cause any adverse issues with the alert?

Comment: Is this all of your code? It seems like there might be to your swal? If I put just what you have listed here into a jsfiddle, it seems to be working just fine.
https://jsfiddle.net/sm1215/fvyqmrar/

Comment: @sm1215 - I'll make some additional notes above.  Thank you for the help!